# HP530 Ubuntu 12.04 Black screen after restart

Tags: screen

I installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 12.04. I started the machine and was able to login successfully the first time. Upon any restarts I see a black screen, then I hear the audio drum roll that is played when it is time to login, I however only have a black screen. I then loaded up grub loader by holding shift during booting and set to nomodeset(I believe this goes low graphics default). I am able to boot in. I downloaded and ran boot repair, below you can find the boot report. Upon running boot repair and restarting it boots in fine the first time. However on subsequent attempts it will just go to the black screen. Please Help!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6433303/

Comment: You should try changing the driver to your graphics card. Also check your screen brightness on bootup.